# How to select a column which contains user input?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I would like to perform a MYSQL query to select elements where the title in the database somehow contains the user input. In order to understand what I want:

A title in the database might be

```
"The three kids are playing in the yard".
```

A user might search for "kids playing" and I want him to find that title. Currently I am using

```
SELECT title FROM someTable WHERE title LIKE "%sometitle%"`
```

However this won´t return the title as the word "are" is missing in the user input and therefore nothing will be returned.
Is there a way to select the title when a user is not entering the exact same word order like in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be to split the search term into 'kids' and 'playing' and generate the LIKE statement dynamically into something like this:

```
SELECT title FROM someTable WHERE title LIKE '%FIRST%SECOND%'
```

Here FIRST would be replaced by kids and SECOND would be replaced by playing. So practically you would insert a % between every single search term.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it using [MySQL full Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) also:

Either, [Boolean Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) Or [Full Text Search using Query Expansion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html).

Let's look at [Boolean Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html);

Example table as given on dev.mysql.com:

```
mysql> select * from articles;
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title                 | body                                     |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial   | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  2 | How To Use MySQL Well | After you went through a ...             |
|  3 | Optimizing MySQL      | In this tutorial we will show ...        |
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Tricks     | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...      |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL     | In the following database comparison ... |
|  6 | MySQL Security        | When configured properly, MySQL ...      |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title             | body                                     |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order matters, when the words are quoted:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"comparison database"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

When we remove the quotes, it will search for rows, containing words "database" or "comparison":

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('database comparison' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order doesn't matter now:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('comparison database' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

If we want to get rows, containing either word "PostgreSQL" or phrase "database comparison", we should use this request:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('PostgreSQL "database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

[Fiddle To Try](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f54/1)

Make sure, that the words, you are searching for, are not in the [list of stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), that are ignored.
(and obviously words like 'is','the' are [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and those are ignored)

**To enhance sorting of the results** in boolean mode you can use following queries:

(Assuming you have total 2 words in user's input string) Then.

```
SELECT column_names, MATCH (text) AGAINST ('word1 word2')
AS col1 FROM table1
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' in boolean mode) 
order by col1 desc;
```

(If you have 3 words in user's input string) Then..

```
SELECT column_names, MATCH (text) AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3')
AS col1 FROM table1
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' in boolean mode) 
order by col1 desc;
```

Using the **first** `MATCH()` **we get the score in non-boolean search mode (more distinctive)**. The **second** `MATCH()` **ensures we really get back only the results we want (with all 3 words)**.